# Refreshing the content pane through an action listener in java

Tags: java, jpanel, refresh, actionlistener

I have a problem while refreshing the content pane of my GUI. I can create a listener that is executed, but I can't manage to access the content pane to update it. Here is my code so far:

Egutegia() and Hasiera() and constructors for JPanels with different data. They load correctly when set to variable centralData from the beggining. My goal is to change between one another when clicking the buttons with their name. So far I only tried to implement one.

The action listener is written in the later part. It prints "reaches here" correctly. However, I dont know how to acces the content pane (content) from there and redraw the corresponding JPanel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyApp{

private static String message1 = "message1";
private static String message2 = "message2";
private static BotMessage botMessage;
private static TopButtons topButtons;
private static JButton[] buttons;
private static JButton b1,b2,b3,b4;
public static JPanel centralData = new Hasiera();


private static class BotMessage extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        double h = getHeight();
        double w = getWidth();
        Font font = new Font("default", Font.BOLD, (int)(h/2));
        g.setFont(font);
        int stw = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(message2); 
        g.drawString(message1, (int)(w*0.02), (int)(3*h/4));
        g.drawString(message2,(int) (w*0.98 - stw),(int)(3*h/4));
        setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
       }


 public static class TopButtons extends JPanel{
     public  TopButtons(JButton buttons[]){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        for (int i=0;i < buttons.length;i++){
            add(buttons[i]);
        }   
     }


 }




 /*
  *   LOADING EVERYTHING INTO A WINDOW
  */

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     botMessage = new BotMessage();      
     b1 = new JButton("Hasiera");
     ActionListener ref = new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             centralData = new Egutegia();
             System.out.println("reaches here");
         }
     };
     b1.addActionListener(ref);
     b2 = new JButton("Egutegia");
     b3 = new JButton("Foroa");
     b4 = new JButton("Txata"); 
     buttons = new JButton[]{b1,b2,b3,b4};
     topButtons = new TopButtons(buttons);



     JPanel content = new JPanel();
     content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
     GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
     c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
     c1.weighty = 0.02;
     c1.gridx = 0;
     c1.gridy = 0;
     c1.gridwidth = 2;
     content.add(topButtons, c1);
     GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
     c2.weightx = 1;
     c2.weighty = 1;
     c2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
     c2.gridx = 0;
     c2.gridy = 1;
     content.add(centralData, c2);
     GridBagConstraints c3 = new GridBagConstraints();
     c3.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
     c3.weighty = 0.04;
     c3.gridx = 0;
     c3.gridy = 2;
     content.add(botMessage, c3);


     JFrame window = new JFrame("MY APP");
     window.setContentPane(content);
     window.setSize(400,600);
     window.setLocation(100,100);
     window.setVisible(true);
     window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it. I needed to declare content as a static variable in the beggining of the myApp class, and not in the main class, to acces it.